# storing string and characters in two dimensional array (C)

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, fgets, getchar

I am trying to write a program to simulate a DFA. what I need to do is to take a number of input from the user and save it in two independent arrays(use it as row and columns), and then create a third array(2d) that acts as a table of values for the first two arrays.

e.g: array2 = {a, b}  array1 ={q1,q2,q3} 
array[array1][array2] = (TABLE BELOW)

```
  a   b
```

========

q1| v1 v2

q2| v3 v4

q3| v5 v6

PROBLEMS:

1) I can't save the strings q1,q2,q3... in array

2) the second array values somehow overwrite the first array values,(maybe because i am using the same variable as their counter? if i change the counter variable for the second loop, it gives segmentation fault

It would be great if someone could point out which part I am doing wrong.

EDIT: the segmentation problem was solved, thanks to answers by coolguy and jayesh. I still have one problem, its that the array1 doesn't return a string, it returns only character, if i enter q1 it returns q only.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// Function declaration
void clearNewLines(void);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // Number of states and number of alphabets of DFA
    int numStates;
    int numAlphabets;

    // Array for name of alphabets, and name of states
    char nameOfAlphabets[numAlphabets]; 
    char nameOfStates[numStates];

    // Saving transition table
    char *transitionTable[numStates][numAlphabets];

    // Read numStates 
    printf("Enter the number of STATES:");
    scanf("%d",&numStates);

    // Flush STDIN
    clearNewLines();

    // Read the nameOfStates 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numStates;i++){   
        printf("Name of STATES:");
        fgets(&nameOfStates[i], 100,stdin);
    }// End of for-loop to read nameOfStates

    // Read numAlphabets
    printf("Enter the number of ALPHABETS: ");
    scanf("%d", &numAlphabets);

    // Flush STDIN
    clearNewLines();

    // Read name of alphabets

    for(i=0;i<numAlphabets;i++){

        printf("Name of ALPHABETS:");
        nameOfAlphabets[i] = getchar();

        // Flush STDIN 
        clearNewLines(); 

    }// End for-loop to read alphabets

    // Get the transitionTable[states][alphabets] 
    int row;
    for(row=0;row<numStates;row++){

        int col;
        for(col=0;col<numAlphabets;col++){

            printf("Enter Transition From %c to %c: ",nameOfStates[row],nameOfAlphabets[col]);
            printf("\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}// End of main function

/*
*
*   clearNewLines - clear any newline character present at the STDIN
*/
void clearNewLines(void)
{
    int c;
    do
    {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int numStates;
 int numAlphabets;
 char nameOfAlphabets[numAlphabets];
 char nameOfStates[numStates];
```

Here,you are making arrays of uninitialised `int`s which cause the segmentation fault. Move the array initializations after the respective `scanf`s so that the two `int`s get initialized before making the array.

```
char *transitionTable[numStates] [numAlphabets];
```

Move the above line after the two `scanf`s.

Comment: oh yea! i am surprised how come i didn't see the mistake!

Answer (score 3):

```
int numStates;
int numAlphabets;

char nameOfAlphabets[numAlphabets]; 
char nameOfStates[numStates];
char *transitionTable[numStates][numAlphabets];
```

Here `numAlphabets` and `numStates` are uninitialized.

Move definition after the `scanf`.

Like

```
    int numStates;
    int numAlphabets;

  // Read numStates 
    printf("Enter the number of STATES:");
    scanf("%d",&numStates);

   // Read numAlphabets
    printf("Enter the number of ALPHABETS: ");
    scanf("%d", &numAlphabets);

    char nameOfAlphabets[numAlphabets]; 
    char nameOfStates[numStates];
    char *transitionTable[numStates][numAlphabets];
```

Comment: thank you. Do you know how to solve the problem of storing the string? it still doesn't return the string